# A specific question about the derivation of the probability density function for a normal RV

Tags: probability, statistics

Please check out the red box below.

**My Question**

Why is it $g(x^2 + y^2)$ and not $g(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ if the distribution of darts is by distance only?  The square root would come from the Pythagorean Theorem.

**My (poor) attempt at understanding**

I think if there is a square root, then you cannot split $g(x,y)$ cleanly into two functions. This would violate the independence of $X$ and $Y$ in $(X,Y)$. However, I'm pretty sure distance needs a square root because of the Pythagorean Theorem. I would also note the square root never rears its head later in the derivation or in the density formula which troubles me. I was also thinking that it might be akin to variance being the square of the standard deviation... but still I thought the Pythagorean Theorem was pretty cut and dry and needs a square root for the hypotenuse.

As it is, it feels like the distribution of where the dart lands depends on the square of the distance to the center. That would not be intuitive to me but the "formula part" would make more sense.

Thank you for your patience with a slow but earnest learner!!!

---

[image]

Comment: Using your function, $g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ would be proportional to $g(|x|)g(|y|)$. Does that affect your later calculations?

Comment: I believe it does. Because what we desperately need in the derivation is to show that the function $g$ must be an exponential. If you have the square root it ruins everything. $g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) = g(|x|)g(|y|)$ By the way, I'm not sure how you can turn the square root of a sum of two squares into just multiplying them like that... I am a super newbie... can you step by step enumerate the logic for me? I would really appreciate it. Also, can you provide intuition more than just, "it would not work otherwise" especially in context with darts and distance to the origin. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$ g\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) = h(x^2+y^2)$$ where $h = g(\sqrt{x})$ so there is no difference between the two assumptions. All the argument is at that point is that the density must be a function of the distance, but a function of the distance squared is a function of the distance. Taking it to be $g(x^2+y^2),$ $g\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$ or $g((x^2+y^2)^{128,000})$ are all equally valid, but the first is most convenient for the remainder of the argument.

Comment: Thank you for your expertise. Is this a fair way to think about it... I could state it as $g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ since $(X,Y)$ depends only on distance from the origin. But for convenience sake this can be "simplified" by using another function $h(x^2+y^2)$ where the square root is incorporated into $h$ and taken out of the input. I cannot simplify $h(x^2+y^2)$ any further without losing the assumption that the density must be a function of distance. Is that the right track of thinking? What's the proof that you can't simplify $h$ further?

Comment: I don't think you're quite getting it. You seem to grasp that $h$ is just a simple transformation of $g,$ but there's no reason to care whether or not you can simplify $h$ further (and I'm not sure what you even mean by simplify). The point is that $g(r^2)$ is a perfectly valid way of expressing a generic function of $r.$ Since $r\ge 0,$ any function $g(r)$ can be written as $h(r^2)$ for some function $h.$ Since everything's generic and these are just names, may as call $h$ "$g.$"

Comment: Okay I think I understand now. I will have to meditate on this but I think I'm seeing the light.